# Sorting the arraylist by the values user has inputted

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

How can i sort the arraylist if the user inputs values himself. For example if user adds: Ben, Tom, Jack. And then presses play it opens a new activity and shows the name Jack. if you press back, Tom. And then Ben. I want it to be the other way around. I tried collections.sort() but had no luck with it. Any other ideas?

The array:

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

The way user adds names:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
        String input = mYrasytiVarda.getText().toString();
        if(input.length() > 0)
        {
            // add string to the adapter, not the listview
            adapter.add(input);


            // no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is done by the adapter.add() method
        }else{
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Klaida:");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Blogai yrašytas vardas");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// here you can add functions
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }
```

Here I get the names and send them to the other activity:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // count items
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    String obj = adapter.getItem(i);
                    // send items to other activity
                    Intent pradetiZaidima = new Intent(v.getContext(), ZaidimasActivity.class);
                    pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", obj);
                    startActivity(pradetiZaidima);

                }
            }
```

Here I display them:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zaidimas);
        //get the player list from ZaidejaiActivity
        Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
        String myVal = recdData.getString("playerList");

        //show the player list

        mZaidejas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ZaidejoVardas);
        mZaidejas.setText(myVal);


            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
            for (i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                String obj = adapter.getItem(i);
                // send items to other activity
                Intent pradetiZaidima = new Intent(v.getContext(), ZaidimasActivity.class);
                pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", obj);
                startActivity(pradetiZaidima);

            }
```

... you create the activity once for each item in the list, in the order they are stored in the ArrayAdapter. You could just iterate through the items in the reverse order. 
Eg:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = adapter.getCount()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                String item = adapter.getItem(i);

                Intent pradetiZaidima = new Intent(v.getContext(), ZaidimasActivity.class);
                pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", item);
                startActivity(pradetiZaidima);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I initialized the adapter like this: {adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list); }. However with your code the list doesnt contain any values. The thing is I want to have the new activity for each item in the list. I just need it to be from first item to last. Not the last to first.

Comment: Apologies I must be misremembering. Nevertheless you can reconstruct the list, I will edit my answer with more information.

Comment: sorry but your code didnt answer the question I asked. With your code now i get the users inputs in one activity. I dont want that. Like I said:  I want to have the new activity for each item in the list. I do. But i need to make it somehow, so that the first activity it opens is the first input, not the last.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying, I thought you were describing the erroneous behaviour. I will edit again with this in mind.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But I think that i did something wrong. My idea is that  when the new activity starts it shows the first name(it finally worked) and when the player presses button next it shows the second name. Is that even possible if all these names are in the string myVal?

Comment: If you need this in addition to the back-button function you described originally, then you could add an `onClick()` to your next button which takes an action then generates a `back` action, which would take you to the next activity in the stack (ie the next name in the list).